# Парадокс Монти Холла

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Приветствую!

Не могу понять смысл [проблемы Монти Холла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0). Решил провести эксперимент и опытным путем определить соотношение победителей/проигравших. **[Вот сам скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/akdygpwe/)**.

Вопрос: Кто может на пальцах объяснить, что я делаю не так? Почему результаты моей симуляции расходятся с теми, о которых говорится в статье?

Развернутый вопрос. Сделал такой класс:

```
function MontyHallState()
    {
    // Изначально все 3 двери — закрыты:
    this.doors = [0, 0, 0];
    this.doorsOpened = 0;

    // За одной из дверей есть приз:
    this.prize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    // Игрок выбрал одну из дверей:
    this.choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    this.openDoor = function()
        {
        /*
        Если осталось закрытыми меньше 3 дверей,
        то ф-ция возвращает false, иначе —
        «открывается» случайная дверь, за которой нет приза, при этом
        не та, которую выбрал игрок —
        должны быть удовлетворены условия:
        this.doors[openDoor] === 0
        и
        openDoor !== this.choice
        */
        }

    this.changeChoice = function()
        {
        /*
        Значение this.choice должно поменяться таким образом, что
        новое значение должно отличаться от текущего, при этом
        не должно указывать на уже открытую дверь —
        должно быть удовлетворено условие
        this.doors[this.choice] === 0
        */
        };
    }
```

Алгоритм симуляции:

1. Для тех, кто хочет менять первоначальный выбор:

   a. Создаем экземпляр объекта (выбор двери сделан)

   b. Открываем дверь, за которой точно нет приза

   c. Меняем выбор
2. Для тех, кто уверен в первоначальном выборе:

   a. Создаем экземпляр объекта (выбор двери сделан)

   b. Открываем дверь, за которой точно нет приза

Сравниваем значения членов `prize` и `choice`. Если значения совпадают — приз получен.

Проделаем этим манипуляции по 10000 раз для обоих вариантов поведения ([еще раз — скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/akdygpwe/)). Я увидел следующие результаты:

> Don't change choice
>
> Winners: 3408
>
> Losers: 6592
>
> ---
>
> Change choice
>
> Winners: 3345
>
> Losers: 6655

Как видим, процент успеха для обоих случаев примерно одинаковый — ≈33%. Если Повторить опыт несколько раз, убедимся, что такой исход является обыкновением в этой ситуации.

Если рассматривать модель, при которой есть не 3, а 4 двери, окажется, что процент успеха будет составлять ≈25%.

Если опыт проведен верно, то можно ли Парадокс Монти Холла считать несостоятельным? Если опыт проведен неверно или сделаны не те выводы, то какие именно?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Bars: Что-то странное у вас в коде. Почему `while (montyHall.openDoor())`? По описанию парадокса, открытие дверей и смена решения происходит лишь один раз.

Comment: @VladD, просто я рассматривал так же и другие модели — с 4 и более дверьми. В случае с 3 дверьми (по умолчанию) этот цикл больше раза и не выполняется:

>     this.getRandomSecret = function(allowWin) {
>         var res = false;
>         if (this.doors.length - this.doorsOpened < 3)
>             return false;
>         ...


> Если осталось закрытыми меньше 3 дверей, то ф-ция возвращает false

Comment: @Bars, откровенно говоря, тут все настолько предопределено, что в моделировании смысла нет.

Для случая *выбор не меняем* -- очевидно, что угадываем в 1/3 случаев.

А в случае *меняем выбор* получается такая ситуация:

- угадали (1

Comment: @avp, именно это я и вынес из статьи, именно это и не понял. Почему

> не угадали (2/3)

Почему не 2/3, а не 1/3 (а если точнее, то почему не 1/2)? И главное — почему результаты теста не сходятся с этими рассуждениями?

Comment: @Bars, Вы спрашиваете: "Почему не угадали -- 2/3"?

Потому что *угадали* это 1/3 (1 == 1/3 + 2/3).

А 1/2 тут вообще не при чем. 

При стратегии *меняем выбор* **реально** (все остальное это запутывающие слова) выбор делаем **один раз** (в самом начале выбирая одну дверь из трех, отсюда и 1/3). Далее все уже предопределено.

Comment: > 1 = 1/3 + 2/3

Это ясно. Мне ясно, почему в знаменателе 3 (потому что дверей — 3). Меня смущает, что по какой-то причине вы отдаете шансы именно другой двери. Почему не мыслить от обратного: «Выбрали дверь №2. Третью дверь открыли, за ней козел. Шансы, что мы *не угадали с выбором двери — 1/3*. Следовательно, 2/3 — на то, что авто стоит-таки за дверью №2, значит, дверь менять не нужно».

> А что Вы делаете не так? -- моделируете какую-то другую ситуацию.

Как тогда сделать верную модель?

Comment: Как сделать верную модель?

Очень просто. Берете 2 случайных числа: r1 и r2  (1, 2 или 3). Первое -- выигрышная дверь, второе выбор игрока. 

Для стратегии *выбор не меняем* -- выигрыш при r1 = r2.

Для стратегии *меняем выбор* -- выигрыш, соответственно, наоборот - r1 != r2.

(и не надо ничего усложнять в данном случае, вводя разные объекты, функции и т.п.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Опыт проведён не верно. Чтобы получить вероятность 2/3 из Парадокса Монти-Холла, необходимо *всегда* менять выбор, когда ведущий просит выбрать дверь во второй раз.

Из [статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0):

> если вы меняете
> дверь после действий ведущего, то вы
> выигрываете, если изначально выбрали
> проигрышную дверь (тогда ведущий
> откроет вторую проигрышную и вам
> останется поменять свой выбор чтобы
> победить). А изначально выбрать
> проигрышную дверь можно 2 способами
> (вероятность 2⁄3), то есть если вы
> меняете дверь, вы выигрываете с
> вероятностью 2⁄3.

Для случае 4 и более дверей, *ведущий открывает все двери с козами кроме одной* двери (плюс ещё остаётся дверь с машиной). Одна из оставшихся дверей была выбрана игроком изначально.

- вероятность что игрок выбрал изначально дверь с машиной равна 1/4
- то есть вероятность что игрок выбрал изначально дверь с козой равна 3/4
- остались две двери (за одной из них машина): одну из них изначально выбрал игрок. Если за ней коза (вероятность 3/4), то при смене двери игрок находит машину.

Чтобы прочувствовать решение, можно [рассмотреть 1000 дверей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80):

> если представить что дверей не 3 а,
> скажем 1000, и после выбора игрока
> ведущий убирает 998 лишних, оставляя 2
> двери: ту которую выбрал игрок и еще
> одну. Очевидно, что вероятность
> нахождения приза за каждой из них
> вовсе не ½. Гораздо большая
> вероятность его нахождения, а именно
> 0.999, будет иметь место при смене решения и выборе двери отобранной из
> 999. В случае с 3 дверьми логика сохраняется, но вероятность выигрыша
> при смене решения ниже, а именно 2⁄3.

Симуляция на Питоне, подтверждает теорию:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

CAR, GOAT = 'car', 'goat'
DOORS = [CAR] + [GOAT]*2
win_keep = win_change = 0
for round in range(1, 10001):
    doors = list(DOORS)

    # make the first choice
    random.shuffle(doors)
    win_keep += (doors.pop() == CAR)

    # remove all but one door
    while len(doors) > 1:
        doors.remove(GOAT)

    # change the choice
    win_change += (doors[0] == CAR)

print("{:.1%} {:.1%}".format(float(win_keep)/round, float(win_change)/round))
```

#### Вывод

```
33.7% 66.3%
```

То есть 1/3 если не менять дверь и 2/3 если менять.

Чтобы провести тесты для `4` дверей достаточно кол-во коз изменить в определении `DOORS`.

Answer (score 4):

[@Bars](/users/8906/bars), в  комментарий не влезает, поэтому пример программы моделирования в виде ответа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int m = 3;
  if (av[1] && strcmp(av[1], "-d") == 0) {
    m = 1000;
    av++;
    if (av[1]) {
      m = atoi(av[1]);
      av++;
    }
    if (m < 3)
      m = 3;
  }
  int i, n = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "10000001"), nw1 = 0, nw2 = 0;
  if (n < 1) {
    srand(time(0));
    n = -n;
  } else if (!n)
    n = 10;

  // n rounds simulation for m doors 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int choice, car, door[m];
    memset(door, 0, sizeof(door[0]) * m);
    door[car = (rand() % m)] = 1;  // car
    // alg 1 -- first choice
    nw1 += door[choice = (rand() % m)];
    // alg 2 -- change door
    if (car != choice) 
      nw2++;
  }

  printf ("%d doors win simulations %d: no change -- %.2f%%  change -- %.2f%%\n", 
          m, n, (nw1 * 100.0) / n, (nw2 * 100.0) / n);
}
```

Компилировать gcc или g++, с аргументами (-d , +/-число циклов и т.п.) думаю, разберетесь...